# Get elements from a Jquery selector via index

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to iterate the elements of a jQuery selector and obtain certain data from each element. More specifically, I need to obtain the `<p>` tags from them.
The function `.get(index)` works well, and it gets the correct element, but then I can't obtain the `<p>` elements.

```
var n_rows = $('#r_data_5').text();
var data = $('#datos_ocultos > ul > li');
var index = 0;
for (let i = 0; i< parseInt(n_rows); i++){
 for(let j=index; j<4;j++){
  var a = data.get(index).find('#r_data_0').text(); //this is getting an error
 }
}
```

```
<div id="datos_ocultos" style="display: none;">
 <p class="report_data" id="r_data_5">
  <t t-esc="number_rows" />
  </p>
  <ul>
   <t t-foreach="report_ids" t-as="report">
    <t t-if="report.teacher_id and report.subject_id">
     <li>
      <p class="report_data" id="r_data_0">
       <t t-esc="report.teacher_id.name " />
      </p>
      <p class="report_data" id="r_data_1">
       <t t-esc="report.subject_id.display_name " />
      </p>
      <p class="report_data" id="r_data_2">
       <t t-esc="report.course_id.display_name " />
      </p>
      <p class="report_data" id="r_data_3">
       <t t-esc="report.teacher_id.work_email " />
      </p>
//more code
```

> Error: Uncaught TypeError: data.get(...).find is not a function

[image]

Comment: Add the html snippet here, that would help.

Answer (score 2):

`.get(ix)` yields the `DOMNode` at that index. You want to use `.eq(ix)` to get the jQuery object, in order to be able to run `.find` operations etc.

You could also use the DOM node as context for the selector:

```
var a = $('.r_data_0', data.get(index)).text();
```

Note also that I've updated the selector to search by class rather than id. This of course wont work without a corresponding change in markup.

You need to make that change, as ID's are supposed to be unique within the document, and selectors are working based on that assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use simple `each` iterator?

```
$('#datos_ocultos ul li').each(function(){
    var a = $(this).find('#r_data_0').text();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the p tags from html like this:

```
$('ul li').each(function()
{
  console.log( this.innerHTML); // This is your p tags
});
```